# Implementation of Insertion Sort Algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I was trying to implement the insertion sort algorithm in python and was able to code it as below, I am not getting the whole array sorted and was wondering if this implementation has the proper thought process behind it, if not I would greatly appreciate if someone can help me in understanding it as the function is considering the sorted part of the array when inserting an element from the unsorted part. Also, in your review kindly consider if the implementation is correct and if so what can make my solution output correct.

```
def insertion_sort(array):
    for i in range(1, len(array)):
        for j in reversed(range(1, i)):
            if array[j-1] > array[j]:
                temp = array[j-1]
                array[j-1] = array[j]
                array[j] = temp
    return array

to_sort = [4, 3, 1, 5, 6, 2]
print(insertion_sort(to_sort))
```

This is the output I got:
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2]

**tl;dr:
Insertion Sort algorithm not giving perfect output. Is implementation correct and what can be done to fix the output.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of your function would be to shift `array[i]` into the sorted partition, but it actually does that for `array[i-1]`, because the inner loop starts with `j` equal to `i-1`.

So the easy fix is to change:

```
    for j in reversed(range(1, i)):
```

to:

```
    for j in reversed(range(1, i + 1)):
```

### Improvements

More Pythonic would be to use the capability of `range` to produce a descending range:

```
    for j in range(i, 0, -1):
```

When the `if` condition is not true, it is useless to continue the inner loop, as then it is guaranteed that the `if` condition will never be true in the rest of the inner loop's iterations. So add a break:

```
        if array[j-1] <= array[j]:
            break
        temp = array[j-1]
        array[j-1] = array[j]
        array[j] = temp
```

As these swaps will *always* move the same value to the left, i.e. `array[j]` will always be the value that originally was at `array[i]`, it is less costly to first find the index where `array[i]` should be moved to, and then perform a single rotation to get it there.

```
def insertion_sort(array):
    for i in range(1, len(array)):
        temp = array[i]
        for k in range(i - 1, -1, -1):
            if array[k] <= temp:
                break
        else:
            k = -1
        # rotate
        array[k+2:i+1] = array[k+1:i]
        array[k+1] = temp
    return array
```

I used `k` here, so not to confuse it with the meaning of `j` in the original code: `k` is `j - 1`.

This search for `k` (or `j`) can be done with a call to `next`:

```
def insertion_sort(array):
    for i in range(1, len(array)):
        temp = array[i]
        j = 1 + next((k for k in range(i - 1, -1, -1) if array[k] <= temp), -1)
        array[j+1:i+1] = array[j:i]
        array[j] = temp
    return array
```

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for, it turns out understanding what you write down in code is as important as coding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are never touching the last element of the array, I suggest changing `len(array)` with `len(array)+1`, i.e.,

```
def insertion_sort(array):
    for i in range(1, len(array)+1):
        for j in reversed(range(1, i)):
            if array[j-1] > array[j]:
                temp = array[j-1]
                array[j-1] = array[j]
                array[j] = temp
    return array
```

This is because `i` has maximum value `len(array)-1` and `j` has as maximum value `i-1`, which is `len(array)-2`.
However, the last element in the array has index `len(array)-1`.

Comment: I think putting the `+1` on the second loop is better. The first iteration of the outer loop in your code is wasted, since `range(1, 1)` is empty. Using `i+1` in the second loop doesn't have any wasted iterations.